# (springboot) jar not executable on other computers

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have a spring Boot application. I package it with maven, and I execute it with java -jar xxx.jar. The application is running. However if I copy the jar on another machine (same java version, same OS) I get a dependency error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name
'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaConfiguration':...
...
Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0 
...
Bean instantiation via factory method failed
...
 Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: 
Failed to instantiate [javax.sql.DataSource]: 
Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
```

I added debug=true to show the classpath during execution, but it seems the same on both machines (there were issues with classpath order between maven execution and java execution)

EDIT: actually the problem is not changing machine: if I just move the jar in another folder, I get the same error. If I look at the correct running process it seems fairly obvious that in the classpath there are references to ther project target folder that cannot be satisfied...

Original machine is iOS, I tried the jar on other iOS and a Centos machine with same result.

I thought jar was very portable for deployment, so I don't understand if there is a better way of deploying the application or some environment variable I'm not taking into account

EDIT: I use maven. I do

```
mvn package
```

or
    mvn clean install

and I have the dependencies mentioned in the answer

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
   </dependency>

<plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Perhaps a configuration pointing to, or attempting to include/import, an external config file using a relative path (which no longer exists when starting from another directory).

Comment: Could you give more detail on what you do to "package it with maven"? There are a lot of ways one could create a jar file designed for distribution using Maven.

Comment: Yes, you need to generate a "Fat jar", are you using maven or gradle?

Comment: I use maven , I do package or clean install, I added info in the post...I'm looking for other way of deploying maybe...

Comment: What is the stack trace of the NullPointerException?

Comment: @AndyWilkinson thanks, reading again the stacktrace I solved the problem...

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a **Fat jar** (a jar file with all the dependencies), you can find a more detailed info [here](http://www.baeldung.com/deployable-fat-jar-spring-boot), but to let some code in the answer:

Basically what you have to do is check that you have the right dependencies in your pom

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1.RELEASE</version>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
```

Then you should do

```
mvn clean install
```

And run it!

```
java -jar <artifact-name>
```

**EDIT**

What do you see if you do a repackage? `mvn clean package spring-boot:repackage`

Comment: I edited the post, I had exactly what you said, and that is exactly the problem. spring-boot:run is working fine. java -jar is also working fine, but if I move the jar, I can't execute it

Comment: Mmm, weird, i have the same configs and my server is running fine, just needs a jvm installed, i edited the question

Answer (score 0):

Your `HibernateJpaConfiguration` bean cannot be created. It looks it has some property declared in a `@Configuration` annotated class or in the `application.properties` resource file. Some property that has a relative path in it, and when you move the jar it cannot find that property.

Answer (score 0):

Actually it was a trivial issue: a directory had to be listed from a relative path and in order to execute the jar somewhere else I had to just create that directory.

The error wasn't properly catched so the stacktrace was showing failure in dependencies and I missed the simple reality: java.lang.NullPointerException....

Thanks to @AndyWilkinson for making me read the stacktrace again...